# Objective C: Include class and call method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have built a class which has a few methods in it, once of which returns an array, lets call this class A.

I have a second class, class B, which I would like to use to call the method from class A.

But, now how do I call that method from class A and store what is returned in a var in class B?  Do I have to initiate the class?  I have made sure to include the .h file from class A into class B.

Thanks for helping a newbie.

UPDATE:

Here is how I thought I could do this (DataStore is my class A and pushRideData is my method that returns an array):

```
DataStore *store = [[DataStore alloc] init];
trailsArray = [store pushRideData];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have files `A.h`, `A.m` `B.h` and `B.m` to define your two classes, then you need to do the following:

1. Make sure `A.h` and `B.h` are `#import`ed into your projects PCH file (this is the easiest/fastest way, but you could also choose to import the files into all the .m files, instead).
2. If you refer to a class -- say, `B *something` in `A.h` -- before that class's header file is imported, then use a forward class declaration to shut up the compiler.  I.e. `@class B;` before the `@interface A:NSObject` in `A.h`
3. If you want to call an instance method of a class, you need to instantiate the class as you describe. Or, if the instance is created somewhere else, you'll need some mechanism to retrieve it.  A class method, perhaps, or a global variable or a controller or something like it.

None of this is really that much different than straight C save for a formal notion of Objects (as opposed to malloc'ing a bunch of memory and passing around pointers).

Comment: I had a similar question and your answer got me all setup. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's a fairly abstract question. Yes, you need an instance to be able to store instance variables in it. You will need to allocate and init the instance, assinging it to an instance or local (pointer) variable in the calling class unless it is one of the several in the Cocoa Touch frameworks which use the singleton pattern, such as the application delegate. Such singletons have special case-specific class methods for obtaining the singleton instance.

Comment: Sorry for being abstract, I updated my question with an example of how I though I was suppose to do it, but obviously it is wrong and not working.

Comment: DataStore doesn't appear to be a class provided by Apple (I find no docs for it as of iPhone 3.1.3 anyway). So I guess I can't know for sure semantics of how it needs to be used.

But generally you need a pointer to a freshly created object, not just the type declaration:

DataStore *myDataStore = [[DataStore alloc] init];

Comment: And then you would use that instance pointer in the next line:

NSArray *trailsArray = [ myDataStore pushRideData ];

Comment: OK, looks like you've edited it again and that should be correct for the general case, presuming "trailsArray" has been declared as an NSArray pointer previously.